# How to make the last mark invisible in a matplotlib axes subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

Say the marks of an axes subplot is shown as "0,20,40,60,80,100", but I want to make the last mark 100 invisible. Not sure how to do it for a matplotlib axes subplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are setting the positions of x-ticks, you can simply replace the last label by a empty string.

```
import pylab as plt

x=[12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
y=[14, 15, 16, 17, 18]

xticks=[12,13,14,15,16]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y,'o-')

ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks[:-1]+[""])
plt.show()
```

You can also use the following to remove the last x-tick label

```
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    pass
label.set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question didn't specify if you want to hide the tickline in addition to the ticklabel, so if you also want to hide the tickline, this line should do it

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklines()[-2:],visible=False)
```

The order of Matplotlib's ticklabels alternates between bottom and top, moving from left to right. So hiding the last two assumes that you want the ticklabels hidden for both top and bottom. To hide just the bottom one:

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklines()[-2],visible=False)
```

or just the top one:

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklines()[-1],visible=False)
```

I should add that is was meant to be an addition to the previous answer by @imsc and it should be entered after any line which sets the identity of the xticklabels to avoid having their visiblity status reset to True.